# Is there an equivalent to nsiChannel in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I'm porting my Firefox extension to Google Chrome. I make heavy use of `nsiChannel` to read HTTP headers and such, like so:

```js
//initialize the channel in onStartRequest
onStartRequest: function (req /*, ctx*/) {
    var channel = req.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIChannel);
    //...more init stuff here
}

onDataAvailable: function (req, ctx, stream, offset, count) {
    //.. store the data from the stream for later processing...
    stream_ctx.bstream.setInputStream(stream);
    stream_ctx.bytes += stream_ctx.bstream.readBytes(count);
},
```

Does Google's Chrome browser have the equivalent functions? I've seen a bit of HTTP-listener-style stuff, but so far I haven't seen anything that has all of the features of `nsiChannel`. Still, Mozilla's docs on accessing the low-level stuff like this are a little better organized than what I've found for Chrome, so I might have just missed it.

EDIT:

I'm using a stream listener, starting with this:

```js
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService)
  .newChannel(swf_url, null, null)
  .asyncOpen(stream_listener, null);
```

Here `swf_url` is the URL to a YouTube video.

The `stream_listener` is implemented to grab all the bytes from the incoming stream like so:

```js
onDataAvailable: function (req, ctx, stream, offset, count) {
    stream_ctx.bstream.setInputStream(stream);
    stream_ctx.bytes += stream_ctx.bstream.readBytes(count);
},
```

When I get to `onStopRequest` I feed the bytes to a parser/decoder. What I don't know is how to replicate the `onDataAvailable` method to get the bytes into a stream I can feed into my parser.

Comment: Asking for all of nsiChannel might be a bit much, but if you can point to some specific functionality, I could tell you whether it exists or not.

Comment: Re edit: So you want to grab data from the response body? That is not possible yet.

Comment: Drat. If all else fails I can load Mozilla into Chrome (don't ask, it's ugly) but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: If you are the initiator of the request, then you can access the data though: using XMLHttpRequest.